# Why is my ssh connection unauthorized although I have updated my key on the remote machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication

On my local machine I have a public key stored in

```
.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

To be able to log in to a remote machine I copy this key using `ssh-copy-id`:

```
ssh-copy-id user@remote-host
```

On the remote host, I see two lines added to the file `.ssh/authorized_keys` starting with `ssh-dss` and `ssh-rsa`, and ending with the local machine information.

However, when I now log in to the remote machine with

```
ssh user@remote-host
```

I am still asked for a password. Why is that and how can this be fixed?

- The file permissions of `authorized_keys` are correct.
- The following is the result of `ssh -v`:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx [xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/alexander/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/alexander/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexander/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: identity file /home/alexander/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexander/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexander/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.52
debug1: no match: dropbear_0.52
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA XXXX
debug1: Host 'remote_host' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/alexander/.ssh/known_hosts:26
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/alexander/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/alexander/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/alexander/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@remote_host's password:
```

Comment: The log only says that your client has offered the key to the server, but apparently the server didn't accept that, so it reverts to password authentication. the reasons for tjat should be on server side, maybe PubkeyAuthentication or AuthorizedKeysFile aren't set on the server?

Comment: Permissions on authorized_keys file on remote host?

Comment: The permissions on the authorized_keys are correct, and unfortunately I have no log files available I can take a look (because the remote host runs a non-standard linux and is highly configured.). Which file(s) usually contain ssh settings?

Comment: I have found the error: The modes of the overlaying directories where incorrect! After fixing all the permissions and ownerships the passwordless ssh login works. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: So the .ssh dir must be `600` permission and the files inside `700`?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to cat out the contents to the remote host directory or it will not acknowledge the new key and chmod 700 (not 600) both .ssh directories (local and remote host).

After generating the new keypair, enter the command on the local host `cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh <user>@<remotehost> 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'` This will take the output of your authorized keys on your local machine and place it on the remote machine as well. Moreover, you'll need to ensure you have RWX access, and not just RW.

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` does exactly the catting you describe (except for all public keys not just RSA) with some added errorchecking AND setting the permisssions for you.

Comment: `This will take the output of your authorized keys on your local machine`: No, you copy the `id_rsa.pub` file content to authorized_keys on the remote.